# WordPress | Modify rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have start maintaining a web site, that it is build from another person, and I like to modify the rewrite rules applied for a custom post type.

more specific, the custom post type is buidled with the following settings :

```
$args = array(
    ...
    'rewrite'               =>  array(
        'slug'              =>  'myposttype',
        'with_front'        =>  false
    ),
    ....
)

register_post_type('myposttype', $args);
```

The permalink structure is the following:

```
Post name   http://www.mysite.gr/sample-post/
```

but the url structure is the following:

```
http://www.mysite.gr/myposttype/my_post_slug/
```

how can I change it to

```
http://www.mysite.gr/my_post_slug/
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is not a good idea as it may conflict with pages having the same slug.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/) on how to remove the post type name from the url.

Comment: I know, but this is the requirement from my client side

Comment: Try the link, it will help you.